# How correctly logging to files in nuxt?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I have winston to log files. I tried to use nuxt-winston-log module. But it's have hardcode for logs templates and working strange.
I need to log errors and access in files with my own template, where I need content length in bytes, times for request, uuid, pid, etc.

And I create modules for it, where I successfully log errors in hook errorMiddleware. But for access I am using `this.nuxt.moduleContainer.addServerMiddleware` and already tried to use hook `setupMiddleware`. 
But I have incorrect server request time (As I think), and **I have n't response bytes**. Cause, as peoples says I don't have response here, but I am tried to get in `request.on('end')` callback.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.nuxt.hook('render:setupMiddleware', app =>
    app.use((request, response, next) => {
        response.on('close', () => {
            console.log(response)
        })

        next();
  })
);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you explain your answer a little more?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.